# Scala best practices: mapping 2D data

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

What would be the best way in Scala to do the following code in Java in proper functional way?

```
LinkedList<Item> itemsInRange = new LinkedList<Item>();
for (int y = 0; y < height(); y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width(); x++) {
        Item it = myMap.getItemAt(cy + y, cx + x);
        if (it != null)
            itemsInRange.add(it);
    }
}

// iterate over itemsInRange later
```

Over course, it can be translated directly into Scala in imperative way:

```
val itemsInRange = new ListBuffer[Item]
for (y <- 0 until height) {
    for (x <- 0 until width) {
        val it = tileMap.getItemAt(cy + x, cx + x)
        if (!it.isEmpty)
            itemsInRange.append(it.get)
    }
}
```

But I'd like to do it in proper, functional way.

I presume that there should be `map` operation over some sort of 2D range. Ideally, `map` would execute a function that would get `x` and `y` as input parameters and output `Option[Item]`. After that I'll get something like `Iterable[Option[Item]]` and `flatten` over it will yield `Iterable[Item]`. If I'm right, the only missing piece of a puzzle is doing that map operation on 2D ranges in some way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this all in one nice step:

```
def items[A](w: Int, h: Int)(at: ((Int, Int)) => Option[A]): IndexedSeq[A] =
  for {
    x <- 0 until w
    y <- 0 until h
    i <- at(x, y)
  } yield i
```

Now say for example we have this representation of symbols on a four-by-four board:

```
val tileMap = Map(
  (0, 0) -> 'a,
  (1, 0) -> 'b,
  (3, 2) -> 'c
)
```

We just write:

```
scala> items(4, 4)(tileMap.get)
res0: IndexedSeq[Symbol] = Vector('a, 'b, 'c)
```

Which I think is what you want.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it's exactly what I was looking for! These `yield` stuff compherensions look very promising!